# Giving a list of Harshad numbers using Python script

Tags: python, range

After looking around on SO for similair questions and not finding any, I will give it a shot by asking it here. I'll try to be as specific as possible.
Using Python, I am trying to make a piece of code that runs through all possible Harshad numbers and give back an [i] amount of Harshad numbers in a list. To do this, I first made a method isHarshad, which figures out if a number in a list is a Harshad number. Afterwards, I implement this method to print only Hardshad numbers in a list.

```
def isHarshad(i):
    l = list(str(i))
    a = sum([int(e) for e in l])
    if a == 0:
        return False
    if i % a == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def ithHarshad(i):
    a = []
    count = 0
    top = 999999999
    for x in (range (1,top)):
        if isHarshad(x):
            a = a + [x]
            count += 1
            if count == i:
                print(a)
ithHarshad(25)
```

Running this code returns the first 25 Harshad numbers, which is what I want it to do.
Now my question is: Is it possible to form a loop where it checks a range for Harshad numbers, without making a "top" variable as performed in my code? It feels messy to loop to an arbitrary number like 999999.

I hope my question is a bit clear, and thanks in advance for any input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing it with `while True:` And break the loop when enough numbers are generated. In your code you are running through all the possible numbers which is highly inefficient.

```
def isHarshad(i):
    l = list(str(i))
    a = sum([int(e) for e in l])
    if a == 0:
        return False
    if i % a == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def ithHarshad(i):
    a = []
    count = 0
    x = 0
    while True:
        x += 1
        if isHarshad(x):
            a = a + [x]
            count += 1

        if count == i: # Breaks when enough numbers are generated.
            break
    print(a)

ithHarshad(25)
```

This will keep adding 1 to `x` until your count terminates it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure about what do you mean "checks a range". Did you means you want to show all Hardshad numbers between `start` to `end`? Is that true, you can do this:

```
def isHarshad(i):
    l = list(str(i))
    a = sum([int(e) for e in l])
    if a == 0:
        return False
    if i % a == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def ithHarshad(start, end):
    a = []
    count = 0
    for x in (range (start,end)):
        if isHarshad(x):
            a = a + [x]
    print(a)

ithHarshad(50,100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the feedback, using a while True: worked for me.
Here is my solution:

```
def isHarshad(i):
    l = list(str(i))
    a = sum([int(e) for e in l])
    if a == 0:
        return False
    if i % a == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def ithHarshad(i):
    a = []
    count = 0
    x=1
    while True:
        if isHarshad(x):
            a = a + [x]
            count += 1
            x+=1
            if count == i:
                print(a)
        else:
            x+=1
ithHarshad(25)
```

Comment: You don't need to post your own answer again :) And don't run x+=1 in both cases. Just keep `x += 1` below `while True:` It will reduce a line.

Answer (score 0):

My way is literally the easiest and smallest way

```
#get Nums

def getHarshadNums(i):
    return [i for i in range(whatever_the_range_is) if isHarshad(i)]
```